# Java import giving error

Tags: java

Again, I am a java n00b and I am trying to learn from scratch and running into some embarrassing problems.

I got an Account class as follows:Account.java

```
 public class Account 
 {
    protected double balance;

    // Constructor to initialize balance
    public Account( double amount )
{
    balance = amount;
}

    // Overloaded constructor for empty balance
    public Account()
{
    balance = 0.0;
}

    public void deposit( double amount )
{
    balance += amount;
}

    public double withdraw( double amount )
{
            // See if amount can be withdrawn
    if (balance >= amount)
    {
        balance -= amount;
                    return amount;
    }
    else
            // Withdrawal not allowed
                    return 0.0;
}

    public double getbalance()
{
            return balance;
}
  }
```

I am trying to use extends to inherit the methods and variables in this class. So, I used InterestBearingAccount.java

```
 import Account;

 class InterestBearingAccount extends Account
  {
    // Default interest rate of 7.95 percent (const)
    private static double default_interest = 7.95;

    // Current interest rate
    private double interest_rate;

    // Overloaded constructor accepting balance and an interest rate
    public InterestBearingAccount( double amount, double interest)
{
    balance = amount;
    interest_rate = interest;
}

    // Overloaded constructor accepting balance with a default interest rate
    public InterestBearingAccount( double amount )
{
    balance = amount;
    interest_rate = default_interest;
}

    // Overloaded constructor with empty balance and a default interest rate
    public InterestBearingAccount()
{
    balance = 0.0;
    interest_rate = default_interest;
}

    public void add_monthly_interest()
{
            // Add interest to our account
    balance = balance +
                    (balance * interest_rate / 100) / 12;
}

 }
```

I get an error saying import error '.' expected when I try to compile. All the files are in the same folder.

I did javac -cp . InterestBearingAccount

Comment: If they're in the same package you don't need to import.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all the files are in the same folder / package, you don't need to do an import.

Answer (score 4):

When you define your class you can optionally include a `package` statement at the top of the file.  This mandates the package that the class belongs to and should correlate to its position on the file system.  For example, a public class `Account` in package `com.foo` should be defined in the following file hierarchy:

```
com
 |
 |--foo
     |
     |--Account.java
```

As you have omitted the `package` statement both your classes belong to the **anonymous** package.  For classes belonging to the same package there is no need to import classes in order to reference them; this is only a requirement for classes in a different package.

Comment: package is the name of the folder?

Comment: The hierarchy of folders represents the package name.  In the above example the package is com.foo, so you would add "package com.foo'" as the first line in Account.java.

Answer (score 1):

if you're classes are in the same package, it's not necessary to import. Otherwise you should import the package + the Class name.

Comment: SO, what exactly is a package? Is it a folder containing all the required classes?

Answer (score 0):

make InterestBearingAccount class public, like

```
public class InterestBearingAccount {}
```